# Word for accepting rule breaking

Tags: doubled-words

If a manager sees someone breaking a rule but doesn't say something to that individual, the manager is basically saying that doing that is ok. I thought the words sounded like plausible deniability but it is not those two words. What words are they? 2 in total.

Comment: Do you mean "but it *isn't* those two words"?

Comment: "Plausible deniability" means something else entirely.

Comment: If you want an idiom, he **turned a blind eye**.

Comment: Tacit Approval is what I was looking for. TY all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following two-word phrases work:  tacit acceptance," "tacit approval," or "acquiescence in"

Comment: Tacit approval is what I was looking for. TY

Answer (score 0):

The manager [condoned](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/condone) what happened.

> verb (used with object), condoned, condoning.
>
> 1. to disregard or overlook (something illegal, objectionable, or the like):
>      *The government condoned the computer hacking among rival corporations.*
> 2. to give tacit approval to:
>      *By his silence, he seemed to condone their behavior.*
> 3. to pardon or forgive (an offense); excuse:
>      *His employers are willing to condone the exaggerations they uncovered in his résumé.*
> 4. to cause the condonation of; justify the pardoning of (an offense).
> 5. Law. to forgive or act so as to imply forgiveness of (a violation of the marriage vow):
>      *His spouse condoned his infidelity from the early years of their marriage.*

Reference:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/condone